# Determine if a value can be used for a Field / DataType in jOOQ

Tags: java, sql, jooq

In jOOQ, is there any way to determine if a value can be used for a Field / DataType?

e.g.:

```
Field f = <a non-nullable varchar(2)>;

assert f.accepts("");
assert f.accepts("a");
assert f.accepts("ab");

assert ! f.accepts("abc");
assert ! f.accepts(null);
assert ! f.accepts();

Field g = <a nullable unsigned byte>;

assert g.accepts(null);
assert g.accepts(0);
assert g.accepts(1);

assert ! g.accepts("");
assert ! g.accepts("a");
assert ! g.accepts(-1);
assert ! g.accepts(999999);
```

If something like this exists, is it strict, or converting?

e.g.:

- if strict, a `varchar(2)` column would not accept an `Integer` `1`, but would accept a `String` `"1"`
- if converting, a `varchar(2)` column would accept an `Integer` `1`

Also, is it possible for `UpdateSetStep#set(Field field, T value)` (and similar methods) to throw an exception if the field cannot accept the value? (for any reason, like nullability, data type, length, precision, scale, etc.)

Comment: For the record, this question has also been posted to the [jOOQ user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jooq-user/RNwSKXT8Tts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In jOOQ, is there any way to determine if a value can be used for a Field / DataType?

No such feature exists as of jOOQ 3.6. There's a new feature request for this, now: [#4543](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4543).

> Also, is it possible for [`UpdateSetStep#set(Field field, T value)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/UpdateSetStep.html#set-org.jooq.Field-org.jooq.Field-) (and similar methods) to throw an exception if the field cannot accept the value?

You won't be able to override the behaviour of `set()`. But you could add your own data type `Binding` implementations to all data types, and implement your validation when binding variables to the underlying JDBC statement.

For more info about data type bindings, see:
http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/queryparts/custom-bindings/